# Entity Framework Context Caching using Include() and Find()

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm working on optimizing some Entity Framework code and ran into some issues with context caching.

```
var db = new transactionContext(); // lazy loading, proxy creation disabled.

var transactionsOfSameCustomer = db.Transactions.Where(t => t.CustomerId == currentTransaction.CustomerId && t.MostExpensiveItemId != Guid.Empty).Include("Items");

foreach (var transactionOfSameCustomer in transactionsOfSameCustomer)
{
    // method 1: slow
    var mostExpensiveItem = db.Items.Find(transactionOfSameCustomer.MostExpensiveItemId);

    // method 2: fast
    var mostExpensiveItem = transactionOfSameCustomer.Items.Where(i => i.ItemId == transactionOfSameCustomer.MostExpensiveItemId).First();
}
```

The current code (method 1) is using `db.Items.Find()` to locate the most expensive Item in a Transaction, using a field of Transaction, MostExpensiveItemId. When I changed to `transaction.Items.Where()` (method 2) the query became about 40 times faster.

I thought since `Find()` is querying the context before hitting database, it should be similarly fast as using `Where()` on a collection in memory (method 2)?

I'm running Entity Framework 6.0.

Comment: Just to clarify. Do you call `ToList()`/ `First`/or any other method which executes query after `Where()`, because other way query not executed

Comment: BTW: *Where* in combination with *first* will throw an error if *where* returns nothing. I usually work with *FirstOrDefault* instead.

Comment: @Uriil I actually don't. Is it because of that so the query wasn't executed at the line 3 of the code block?

Comment: @Robert good advice. I used First() instead of FirstOrDefault() because I don't expect any of those queries to return null.

Comment: @jim yeah, `Where` is just a query, so it want be executed unless you try to get result

Comment: You probably did that, but just in case: Please also make sure that there exists an index for the *MostExpensiveItemId* column in the DB. If there is none so far, you will be surprised be the performance increase.